# jquery web form builder

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, formbuilder

I'm searching some jquery-ui (or smth similar) library for creating webform by drag&drop. Just to build some kind of XML (with form fields metadata inside) as output
smth like [this one](https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder). It's cool, but it's developing just by 1 man and there are a lot of bugs and very limited functionality.
I'm interesting just building webForm from browser, without any exe applications.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the link you posted, its probably the best option for an XML building formBuilder. There has been a lot of work done in the last few months to solve the known bugs and if you are having a specific problem you can file an issue on github. The author is usually pretty quick to respond.